# DataFrame.at function not working after copying dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, copy

I'm using the .at function to try and save all columns under one header in a list.
The file contains entries for country and population.

```
df = pandas.read_csv("file.csv")
population_list = []
df2 = df[df['country'] == "India"]
for i in range(len(df2)):
   population_list = df2.at[i, 'population']
```

This is throwing a KeyError. However, the df.at seems to be working fine for the original dataframe. Is .at just not allowed in this case?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you don't need to loop over your dataframe to get what you need. Simply use:

```
population_list = df2["population"].tolist()
```

If you really want to use the loop (not recommended when unnecessary), note that the index has likely changed after your filter, i.e not consecutive integers.
Try:

```
for i in df2.index:
    population_list.append(df2.at[i, 'population'])
```

Note: In your code you keep trying to reassign the entire list to one value instead of appending.

Answer (score 0):

In *at* you pass the index value and the column name.

In the case of the "original" DataFrame all is OK, because probably the index contains
consecutive values starting from *0*.

But when you run *df2 = df[df['country'] == "India"]* then *df2* contains
only a **subset** of original rows, so the index does not contain consecutive numbers.

One of possible solutions is to run *reset_index()* on *df2*.
Then the index will again contain consecutive numbers and your code should raise no exception.

## Edit

But your code raises other doubts.
Remember that *at* returns a **single** value, taken from a cell
with particular index value and column, not a list.

So maybe it is enough to run:

```
population_India = df.set_index('country').at['India', 'population']
```

You don't need any list. You want to find just the popupation of India, a **single** value.